# RecylerView not scrolling to last text in android test case with espresso

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-espresso

RecylerView contains a textView "Some content" in the last.I am not able to scroll my recylerview to last text to be shown.I have tried every hit and trial method found to me,but not able to find any solution.

**Code which i have tried**:-

```
1. onView(withId(R.id.recylerview)).perform(scrollToPosition(13));
//my last text view in recyler view is at position 13
2.onView(withText("Some content")).perform(scrollTo(), click());
//my text is "Some content"
```

My problem is that i cannot search it with id as recycler view contains same text view for all 13 items.As i have set text value programmatically.

So this code **cannot apply**:-

```
onView(withId(R.id.txtview)).perform(scrollTo(), click());
```

EspressoCode

```
UiObject2 button9 = device.findObject(By.text("S 5 [None]"));
        button9.click();
        try {
            UiObject srText = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.example.project:id/radio"));
            sText.click();

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.recylerview).atPosition(13))
                .check(matches((hasDescendant(withText("Some content")))));

        UiObject2 button10 = device.findObject(By.text("S 6 [None]"));
        button10.click();
        try {
            UiObject sensorText = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.example.project:id/radio"));
            sensorText.click();

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add [this](https://github.com/dannyroa/espresso-samples/blob/master/RecyclerView/app/src/androidTest/java/com/dannyroa/espresso_samples/recyclerview/RecyclerViewMatcher.java) RecyclerViewMatcher file to your tests. Then add this method to your espresso test so you can use it

```
public static RecyclerViewMatcher withRecyclerView(final int recyclerViewId) {
        return new RecyclerViewMatcher(recyclerViewId);
    }
```

and finally do

```
    onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.recyclerview).atPosition(13))
.check(matches((hasDescendant(withText("Some content")))));
```

So your espresso file would look something like..

```
public class YouEspressoTest {

    public static RecyclerViewMatcher withRecyclerView(final int recyclerViewId) {
        return new RecyclerViewMatcher(recyclerViewId);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void testRecyclerView() {
        ...
        onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.recyclerview).atPosition(13))
                .check(matches((hasDescendant(withText("Some content")))));
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey,i have tried to implement this,but withRecyclerView and atPosition method shows cannot resolve method.

Comment: So you basically need the RecyclerViewMatcher file (as a file) in your androidTest/java/blahblah folder. Then, inside your actual espresso test you need to add the withRecyclerView static method and that's it. The atPosition method is a public method inside the RecyclerViewMatcher so once you have access to it, it should be fine.

Comment: yes,i have implemented but it is still not working.and when debugger reaches their,app gets close with process resume.

Comment: position should be counted from 0 or 1

Comment: position starts from 0

Comment: okey but still it is showing process resume and app gets close when reaches onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.recyclerview).atPosition(13))
                .check(matches((hasDescendant(withText("Some content"))))); here

Comment: plz see edit,i can't add more than this,but it is enough i think.Firstly recyclerview click works for 5 items,then it has to scroll to last so that other items of recylerview click can be used

Comment: hey do u know why  if (targetViewId == -1) {
                    return view == childView;
                } else {
                    View targetView = childView.findViewById(targetViewId);
                    return view == targetView;
                }  this part of code is used.Bcoz my debugger alternatively going there,and stuck in this